# Issue with dim command on TIBASIC

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

I'm tying to put in a command that goes

```
{11,21}STO>dim([A])
```

And I keep getting a syntax error at the first square bracket. The syntax seems correct to me, so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Works on my TI 84+, keep in mind though that there is no square bracket in this command, `[A]` is a token by itself.

Comment: I found it. It's in the matrix menu. Thanks.

Comment: what calculator are you using? what is the code surrounding it? It works for me on a ti-84+ ce and seems to be correct. more info: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/dim

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax appears to be right. The only tip I can give you is a list of button presses to make sure for example you are not doing Bracket A Bracket but selecting the matrix from the matrix menu.

The button presses to do the task you appear to want are:
2nd->left brace(left parenthesis button)->1->1->,->2->1->2nd->right brace(right parenthesis button)->sto(->)->2nd->matrx(x^-1 button)->right arrow->3->2nd->matrx(x^-1 button)->1->right parenthesis

I hope this can be of help, let me know if it works or not.